# <value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations> CFArrayGetValueAtIndex

Tags: iphone

CFArrayGetValueAtIndex im not able to retrieve the value from address book when i tried accessing i get  error

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook= ABAddressBookCreate(); // this will open the AddressBook of               the iPhone
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook); // this copies all the contacts from the Address Book into the array

for (int i =0 ;i<ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);i++)
{
  ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
  NSString *AddBookfirstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPerson);
}
```

this i variable returns statement telling ??? what is the problem here im not able to get the address book value

Comment: Try to recompile in debug mode first.

Comment: im compiling it debug mode only

Comment: hey thanks i was trying to debug keeping in release mode it worked fine changing in the project settings to debug mode

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem and here is what I did to solve the problem:
Since Xcode mentions the "optimization", I select the Project in Project Navigator, click Build Settings, find "Optimization Level", change it to "None[-O0]", and then it works.

After doing this, when you are debugging, Xcode's reaction will slow down, but you could check the variable value that couldn't do before. And the code will be executed sequentially, no jumping any more.